# $ G/N_{1}\cap \cdots \cap N_{r} $ is isomorphic to subgroup of $ G/N_{1} \times \cdots \times G/N_{r} $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How to prove this Lemma: If $ G $ is a group and $ N_{1}, N_{2}, \cdots , N_{r} $ are normal subgroups of $ G $, Then $ G/N_{1}\cap \cdots \cap N_{r} ‎\hookrightarrow‎ G/N_{1} \times \cdots \times N_{r} $ ? In the other hand, $ G/N_{1}\cap \cdots \cap N_{r} $ is isomorphic to subgroup of $ G/N_{1} \times \cdots \times G/N_{r} $. Is there reference for this ?

Comment: Define $G \to G/N_1 \times \cdots \times G/N_r$ by $g \mapsto (gN_1,gN_2,\ldots,gN_r)$ and use First Isomorphism Theorem.